# When I move from fragment b to fragment A after adding my new listitem, my new listitem is not showing in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am making note taking app.i have two `fragments` in my app first `fragment A (ListFragment)` contains the `recycler adapter` .

while when I press adding `floating button` first fragment A `(ListFragment`) is replaced with next `fragment B(AddingFragment)` in which I type new data and then again press adding floating button on fragment B(AddingFragment) to add that new data in data set and then press backfloating  button on my fragment B to move back to `Fragment A`(with recycler adapter) .

This new data item is added to data list every time but never becomes visible in `recycler adapter` in `Fragment A`.

```
 package com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class AddingFragment extends Fragment {

        public AddingFragment()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adding, container, false);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();

            FloatingActionButton floating = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addingfloatingbutton);
            floating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Log.i("floating_button", "floating button 2 clicked");

                    EditText title = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.firsttextview);
                    EditText detial = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.secondtextview);
                    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplication());
                    boolean insert = db.insert(title.getText()+"",detial.getText()+"");

                    if(insert==true)
                    {
                        com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter l = new com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter();
                        ListFragment.it.add(new ListItem(title.getText()+"",detial.getText()+""));
                        l.notifyItemInserted(ListFragment.it.size()-1);//DataSetChanged();

                        l.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        for(int i=0;i<ListFragment.it.size();i++)
                        {
                            Log.i("List item"+i+"", ListFragment.it.get(i).getNoteTitle());
                        }
                        Log.i("insertion", "is added");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i("insertion", "is not added");
                    }
                }
            });

            FloatingActionButton floatings = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addcancelfloatingbutton);
            floatings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                }
            });
        }
    }

//

    package com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.Fragment;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by Anonymous on 12/13/2017.
     */

    public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.holderclas> implements EditDilogue.EditDilougeinterface
    {


         static ArrayList<ListItem> i;
        Context context;
        View view;
        ImageButton share;
        ImageButton edit;
        static int lastposition;
        android.app.FragmentManager fm;

        public ListAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> i,android.app.FragmentManager fm)
        {
            this.i=i;
            this.fm=fm;
        }

        public ListAdapter()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public ListAdapter.holderclas onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            holderclas h = new holderclas(view);
            share = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.share);
            edit =  (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);

            return h;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.holderclas holder, final int position)
        {
            final int y= position;
            lastposition = position;
            final ListItem it = i.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(it.getNoteTitle());
            holder.details.setText(it.getNoteDetail());

               ImageButton b =(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
               b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
               {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view)
                   {
                       Log.i("size", i.size()+"");
                       i.remove(y);
                       notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
               });


            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Log.i("share", "share");
                }
            });

            edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Log.i("edit", i.size()+"edit");
                    EditDilogue ed = new EditDilogue();

                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("title", it.getNoteTitle());
                    args.putString("detail", it.getNoteDetail());
                    ed.setArguments(args);
                    ed.setTargetFragment(new ListFragment(),1);
                    ed.show(fm,"fragment");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return i.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteandadd(String titlestring, String detailstring)
        {
            String oldtitle = i.get(lastposition).getNoteTitle();
            String olddetail = i.get(lastposition).getNoteDetail();

            Log.i("string", titlestring);
            Log.i("string", detailstring);
        }


        public class holderclas extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            TextView title;
            TextView details;


            public holderclas(View itemView)
            {

                super(itemView);
                title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                details=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            }
        }
    }


//

    package com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by Anonymous on 12/13/2017.
     */

    public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements EditDilogue.EditDilougeinterface
    {
        RecyclerView recyClerView;
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
       public static ArrayList<ListItem> it;


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            it = new ArrayList<>();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, parent, false);
            FloatingActionButton floating = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.listfloatingbutton);
            floating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {

                    Fragment frg = new AddingFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
                    trans.replace(R.id.placeholder,frg);
                    trans.addToBackStack("addingfragment");
                    trans.commit();

                    AddingFragment()).addToBackStack("addingfragment").commit();

                }
            });

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {

                ListItem t = new ListItem("Time Bank",
                        "Bank should contain atleast $2000 rupees  then i will leave this matter") ;
                 it.add(t);
            }


            recyClerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle);
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter l = new com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter(it,fm);
            recyClerView.setAdapter(l);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyClerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            if(adapter!=null)
            {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(ListFragment.it.size()-1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void deleteandadd(String titlestring, String detailstring)
        {
            String oldtitle = com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter.i.get(com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter.lastposition).getNoteTitle();
            String olddetail = com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter.i.get(com.example.anonymous.note_taking_app.ListAdapter.lastposition).getNoteDetail();

            Log.i("string", titlestring);
            Log.i("string", detailstring);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why to notify double times ? `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(ListFragment.it.size()-1);`

Comment: actually i was single time but it was not working then i tried

Comment: And also if the new item is getting inserted into your database you can retrieve it from database also rather than declaring some static list or variables,it will be simple I think.

Comment: but before that, i want to check that either this data will be visible or not. for that checking purpose, i am addint his item to list to display it in adapter

Comment: Ok.So is your onResume() is getting called when coming back to the ListFragment? Change and see if it is working. Remove  static from `static ArrayList<ListItem> i;`and from here also `static ArrayList<ListItem> it` . And also remove the method `notifyItemInserted()`.Only keep `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: i did but it is not working

Comment: Can you provide the full source code?

Comment: I have come across the problem . the problem is that when I come back to my list fragment all the references are created again due to which ArrayList is formed again can I somehow use all old references through any call back of  fragment instead if creating new list fragment every time

Comment: Yeah you change the method  `trans.replace(R.id.placeholder,frg);` with `trans.add(R.id.placeholder,frg);` then it will not re-create the fragment everytime when you will call the popbackStack() method. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i did this but brother it is not working

Comment: i think it is again creating the fragment even by using .add finction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161963/discussion-between-soham-and-johon-smuthio).